# Splitting String into String Array Isn't Working Correctly

Tags: java, string, split

```
for (int k = 0; k < dec2.length; k++) {
    System.out.println(dec2[k]);
    String[] tab = dec2[k].split(",");
    System.out.println(tab[0]);
```

When I try this code, `dec2` is a String array containing:

> 41,31
>   11,21
>   42,41
>   12,22

When I try to display `tab[0]`, I get the first number (before the ","), but `tab[1]` returns an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and I don't get why since it's supposed to contain the 2nd number (after the ",").

Comment: That indeed sounds like it should work. Does your `System.out.println(dec2[k])` really print the given list?

Comment: seems like `,` is not an actual comma string.

Comment: No issues with your code. Where are you accessing `tab[1]`?

Comment: Yes it's exactly what is printed. I access tab[1] just after printing tab[0].

Comment: Why not debug line by line and see what `tab[]` contains?

Comment: I suggest debugging. Also, add the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] dec2 = new String[] {"41,31", "11,21", "42,41", "12,22"};
for(int k = 0 ; k < dec2.length ; k++) {

    System.out.println(dec2[k]);
    String[] tab = dec2[k].split(",");


    System.out.println(tab[0]);
    System.out.println(tab[1]);
}
```

I got this output:

```
41,31
41
31
11,21
11
21
42,41
42
41
12,22
12
22

Process finished with exit code 0
```

No exceptions.

You can try to chek `tab.length` before get elements by index, or use `forEach` loop:

```
for(int k = 0 ; k < dec2.length ; k++) {

    System.out.println(dec2[k]);
    String[] tab = dec2[k].split(",");

    for (String part : tab) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable

Comment: Tom, my post contains answer, not only "you code works fine for me".

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
  for(int k = 0 ; k < dec2.length ; k++){

        System.out.println(dec2[k]);
        String [] tab = dec2[k].split(",");
        for (String string : tab) {
            System.out.print(string+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();

}
```

I create a `foreach` loop to iterate the array `tab` to exract both number like:

```
  for (String string : tab) {
            System.out.print(string+" ");
        }
```

Output:

```
41,31
41 31
11,21
11 21
42,41
42 41
12,22
12 22
```

And  if you want use `exact index` try this you'll havr the same output:

```
 for(int k = 0 ; k < dec2.length ; k++){

        System.out.println(dec2[k]);
        String [] tab = dec2[k].split(",");
            System.out.print(tab[0]+" ");
            System.out.print(tab[1]);
        System.out.println();

    }
```

Comment: While this does work, I think OP will find an underlying issue like poorly formatted input. I feel this treats the symptom, not the cause.

Comment: When i just print it like you did, everything seems to work, but when i try to access an exact index of tab it doesn't seem to work, i don't get why.

Comment: @BBaldwin I tested it with exact index and seems work, see the answer above